# Delete image from preview in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

So I am doing multiple images upload, preview and delete in vue js. Here it is what I have:

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" multiple @change="uploadImage" />
<div v-for="(image, key) in productImages" :key="key">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img v-bind:ref="'image'" alt="" src="" />
    <button type="button" @click="removeImage(image, key)"></button>
  </div>
</div

uploadImage(e) {
  let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
      this.productImages.push(selectedFiles[i]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < this.productImages.length; i++) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      this.$refs.image[i].src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.productImages[i]);
  }
},

removeImage(image, index) {
  this.productImages.splice(this.productImages.indexOf(image),1);
  this.$refs.image[index].src = ""
}
```

But here is the problem with this: for example I upload three images and I click to remove second image (in the middle), but it removes image in the middle (which I clicked) and the last image (which I didn't click to remove). So basically with one click it removes two images.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe try  `findIndex` to replace `indexOf`
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding the 3rd one after slicing the array.

index before slice
`0 1 2`

index after slice
`0 1`

The 2 become 1 in the array. Just try to comment the last line

edit: And image is still binding to is index. So I just rewrite the code :

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" multiple @change="uploadImage" />
    <div v-for="(image, key) in productImages" :key="key">
      <div class="image-holder">
        <img v-bind:ref="'image'" alt="" src="" />
        <button type="button" @click="removeImage(image, key)">x</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      productImages: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    uploadImage(e) {
      let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
      for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        this.productImages.push(selectedFiles[i]);
      }
      this.applyImage();
    },

    removeImage(image, index) {
      console.log(this.productImages);
      this.productImages.splice(index, 1);
      this.applyImage();
      //this.$refs.image[index].src = "" // You are hidding the 3rd one that is now in index 1.
    },
    applyImage() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.productImages.length; i++) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          this.$refs.image[i].src = reader.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.productImages[i]);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.image-holder {
  float: left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have tryed this already and it introduces another problem. For example: I upload again three images and I click to remove the second image (middle one) and when I click button it deletes from ```this.productImages``` the right one (middle image), but from preview it deletes the last one and I still can see the image I deleted from ```this.productImages```, so basically I see first and second uploaded image, but it should be first and last image. Hopefully I explained it understandably.

Comment: try to `console.log(selectedFiles.length)` and `console.log(this.productImages.length)` before adding 3 more after deleting the second. Maybe something wierd happen in memories.

Comment: Seems everything okay, honestly I don't know how to fix this issue for now and what to do to fix, tried everything.

Comment: @Edga I just reproduce your issue and found a solution, but I don't like it very much. But in programmation, "if it works dont fix it". You need to re-apply the src for each image in the loop.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you so much for your time. For me now it is most import that it would work the way I need :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually using `v-for` with `ref` has a lot of issues in vue 2. Please follow this issue:

[v-for, refs and access to refs. by array index after Array.unshift](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4952)

As Evan You said, this problem solved in vue 3:

> Note that v-for refs do not guarantee the same order as your source Array.
>
> In the next release you can determine how to register refs yourself by
> passing a function to :ref.

I try to fix your code but I can't find a way. Maybe you have to work with DOM directly.

If I find an answer, I will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call method to render images:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      productImages: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadImage(e) {
      let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
      for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        this.productImages.push(selectedFiles[i]);
      }
      this.refreshImg()
    },
    refreshImg() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.productImages.length; i++) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          this.$refs.image[i].src = reader.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.productImages[i]);
      }
    },
    removeImage(image, index) {
      this.productImages.splice(index, 1);
      this.refreshImg()
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<template>
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" multiple @change="uploadImage" />
  <div v-for="(image, key) in productImages" :key="key">
    <div class="image-holder">
      <img v-bind:ref="'image'" alt="" src="" style="width: 50px;" />
      <button type="button" @click="removeImage(image, key)"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </template>
</div>
```